# WPF - How to add combobox selected value to database

Tags: c#, wpf, database, combobox, selectedvalue

```
tblProd p = new tblProd();
p.categoryname=cb_category.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

I get the string as "**Demo.tbl_category**"
I get the name of the table as string instead of a category name.
I have two properties in my category model category name and description. I have bound the `combobox` source to `observablecollection` of category and I have categoryname as the `displaymemberpath` in `combobox`.

plz help me.thanks in advance.

I m using linq .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an instance of the object and its `ToString`.

`SelectedValue` contains an instance of the object `tbl_category`

Try changing to.

```
p.categoryname=((tbl_category)cb_category.SelectedValue).categoryname;
```

or

```
p.categoryname=cb_category.SelectedValue.categoryname;
```

Comment: Thank bro it works just fine.thanks for the solution